# Directing same output from a 'for' loop to two files?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, mediainfo

Mission: search the drive using variables `%folder%` and `%wildcards%`. The files found are compared by `path-to-file|filesize` to entries in `database.txt`. If a match is found, it is copied to `workinglist.txt` and if not, a new entry is created. The point is to use stored `%duration%` data provided by `mediainfo` to greatly reduce processing time.

```
for /r "%folder%" %%a in (%wildcards%) do (
    findstr /i /c:"%%a|%%~za" "%appdata%\df\database.txt" >>%appdata%\df\workinglist.txt || mediainfo --output="General;%%CompleteName%%|%%FileSize%%|%%Duration%%" "%%a" >>%appdata%\df\workinglist.txt
)
```

The problem is that `database.txt` is supposed to have all possible data, not only the ones dictated by `%folder%` and `%wildcards%`, meaning that any new entries need to be added to both the `workinglist.txt` AND the `database.txt` files.

1. How to also add the data from `mediainfo` to both `workinglist.txt` and `database.txt` without needing another (slow) `mediainfo` query?
2. How do I split that one long line of code to another line or few to make it easier to read and manage?

Comment: what about `findstr ... >> workinglist || ( mediainfo ... >> workinglist  & mediainfo ... >> database)`

Comment: a mediainfo query makes the script very slow and doing it twice would be twice as slow.

Comment: or `findstr ... >> workinglist || for /f %%c in ('mediainfo ...') do ( echo %%c >> workinglist & echo %%c >> database )` ? to avoid executing mediainfo twice

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul not sure how to set the options for the additional ```for``` loop for it to be correctly displayed. wanna format it as an answer?

Comment: It would help if you showed a few lines of `workinglist.txt` and `database.txt`.

Comment: @lit they are both supposed to read like ```d:\path to\media file.mp4|67382943|627843.48300```, as in ```path-to-file|bytes|duration``` but it only works with OP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways to solve this problem. This solution uses `mediainfo` query just once per each new file:

```
rem Insert data of new files in newEntries.txt file
del newEntries.txt 2> NUL
for /r "%folder%" %%a in (%wildcards%) do (
    findstr /i /c:"%%a|%%~za" "%appdata%\df\database.txt" >> "%appdata%\df\workinglist.txt"
    if errorlevel 1 (
        mediainfo --output="General;%%CompleteName%%|%%FileSize%%|%%Duration%%" "%%a" >> newEntries.txt
    )
)

rem Add new entries to both database and workinglist
type newEntries.txt >> "%appdata%\df\database.txt"
type newEntries.txt >> "%appdata%\df\workinglist.txt"
```

Comment: works well on most files but I sometimes get error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.", I think it may be due to special characters in filenames. Investigating now.